# PowerMockito.whenNew is not creating mock actual instance is created

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I have a constructor call in my method under test. I want to mock it because tries to launch a UI. I have mocked the input for constructor as well but still it is trying to create actual instance.

**Production Code :**

```
  public void methodToTest() {
    SaveAsDialog sd = new SaveAsDialog(getSite().getShell());
    sd.setOriginalFile(file);
    sd.open() 
}
```

**Test Code :**

```
   Shell mockShell=Mockito.mock(Shell.class);
    IEditorSite site = Mockito.mock(TestEditorSite.class);
    Mockito.when(site.getShell()).thenReturn(mockShell);
    SaveAsDialog dialogMock=Mockito.mock(SaveAsDialog.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(SaveAsDialog.class).withArguments(site.getShell()).thenReturn(dialogMock);
```

am I missing any thing here, when `SaveAsDialog sd = new SaveAsDialog(getSite().getShell());` line is called it is creating actual instance.

I am running my test with

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SaveAsDialog.class})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass in the instance of `SaveAsDialog` into your class under test as constructor parameter. This would make mocking it quite easy using plain Mockito.

---

If you rather want to surrender to your bad design you have to use *PowerMock* correctly which means you also have to preparer your class under test for mocking:

```
@PrepareForTest({SaveAsDialog.class,YourTestedClass.class})
```

Comment: Thank you timothy-truckle. It worked. It's legacy code i cannot change it.